# Cannot request custom scope from Graph API with clientCredential flow

Tags: javascript, express, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to request an accesstoken from graph with the following scope `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All`. I have granted the API the required scopes - so this shouldn't be a problem.

```
const ccrRequest = {
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All"],
}
const accessToken = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(ccrRequest)
```

The cca is a `ConfidentialClientApplication` and I have triple-checked that my configuration is correct.

When I try to acquire my scope, I get the following error:

> 1002012 - [2021-09-15 12:15:42Z]: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope https://graph.microsoft.com/AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All openid profile offline_access is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).\r\n'

Obviously the error tells me to use the `./default` scope, (which I don't really know why). But according to the documentation, the `./default` scope should give me all my application scopes. This does however not happen:

```
0:'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
1:'openid'
2:'profile'
3:'offline_access'
```

Above, is the scopes that are supplied with my accesstoken when I request the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` scope. Naturally, this does not represent the permissions which I have granted my API in the portal.

When I execute my `fetch()` request, I therefore get the following error:

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Is there something fundamental about the ClientCredentials flow that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the app registration's API permissions tab, add the *Application permission* (not delegated permission) that you need on Microsoft Graph API, and then run admin consent as an Application Administrator at minimum. Then you should be able to use the /.default scope and get the needed permission in the roles claim of the access token.

Openid, profile and offline_access scopes do not make sense in a client credentials scenario.
There is no user so openid and profile scopes do nothing.
The offline_access scope is not needed as you do not need a refresh token. You have the credentials and can use them whenever you need a new token.

Comment: This I have already done actually - The only API permissions that my Express API has is the application permission `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All`. This also means that I think its strange that I get all the other scopes as per default.